# Android Virtual Device, Pressed OK but No response for Mac.........help me

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, android-virtual-device

Android Virtual Device, Pressed OK but No response for Mac.........help me

I am extremely frustrated~!

When I set all the properties on Android Virtual Device Manager on eclipse (sdk 22.6).
Then I press OK, but nothing happen.....
I searched a lots on the Internet,people said that this is the SDK 22.6 Bug.
And I tried so many ways, and still cannot solve the problem,still cannot new an AVD.
Can any one teach me how to fix it ??

p.s. I tried to reinstall,tried to find the execute outside from the eclipse Android Virtual Device Manager(under running eclipse), as below
http://developer.android.com/tools/help/avd-manager.html

Please help~!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this on the command line (without quotes): "cd adt-bundle-mac-x86_64/sdk/tools/" then "run android avd"

Comment: Thanks ElectronicGeek ^^

Comment: I'm not trying to be snotty about this, but when someone's answer works for you, it's good etiquette to accept their answer. If my answer isn't acceptable, I'll be happy to help you more.